# gulp-babel change es6 to es5 require is not undefined

Tags: gulp-babel

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('es6', function() {
    gulp.src('libs/es6/*.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('libs/js'))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('libs/dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('libs/dist'));
});
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

use gulp-babel transform es6 to es5 then get error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
I have try to config .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

but still get the error
define is not defined.
then how to make es6 transform es5 can normal in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your .babelrc file back to:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Now change your gulpfile.js to:

```
gulp.task('es6', function() {
    gulp.src('libs/es6/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        plugins: 'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('libs/js'))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('libs/dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('libs/dist'));
});
```

I just had a similar problem and this worked for me. The only difference is my plugin is called "transform-es2015-modules-amd".

Comment: `Error in plugin "gulp-babel"
Message:
    .plugins must be an array, or undefined`

Comment: @Ryan this answer is now out of date but addresses the issue in the original question. It looks like you need to change `'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd'` to `['babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd']`.

Comment: This worked for me: `function createBrowserifyBundle() {
  const bundleStream = browserify(jsEntry)
    .transform(babelify, { presets: ['es2015'] })
    .transform(ngAnnotate)
    .bundle(); 
  return (
    bundleStream
      .pipe(source(jsDevCustomPiece))
      .pipe(dest(staticPathJs))
  )
}`